# How can yum etc. have failed dependencies?

Tags: package-management, yum, dependencies

Isn't the purpose of yum et al to find the dependency tree and install them in one go? Why does it sometimes seem to do just that and other times just give a simple error?

If the wrong version is installed, why not just install the correct version? Surely installing multiple versions will not trample each other? If they do, does that represent a bad oversight by the developer?

Comment: "If they do, does that represent a bad oversight by the developer?" ... the complexity required for that to work for all possible packages is mind-boggling. I'd even say impossible.

Comment: In some cases I can appreciate your position, you don't want multiple libraries controlling the common hardware etc. But as for pure software, if a specific version of a library is required, why is it necessary that another version should interfere?

Comment: Are you proposing static binaries? No dynamic loading? If you allow dynamic loading, how do you plan to control which version of a library is being loaded?

Comment: But the loader nominates the version it wants, as can be seen by the package dependency, and cannot use a newer (arguably better) version. So what benefit is there to calling an incompatible version, even if it is better?

Comment: Since when does the loader know about package dependencies? Why would the loader know about package dependencies, since it will of course have to run programs that were installed outside of the package management system?

Comment: You're right loader does not know about the package manager, but the package manager knows what library versions are compatible with the installing software/package/tool etc. If the tool being installed requires a specific version but there is no mechanism to nominate it, then perhaps it is an architectural limitation of Linux itself. Ultimately, there is a problem, and I'm trying to find out what it is.